# Is it safe to use exit in a __attribute__((constructor)) function?

Tags: c, gcc, constructor

Is it safe to call `exit()` inside a `__attribute__((constructor))` function like the following example or will it cause issues?

```c
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    return 0;
}

__attribute__((constructor))
void init(int argc, char **argv)
{
    exit(main(argc, argv));
}
```

Comment: Constructors later in the list won't be run before `main` is

Comment: @user253751 it actually will run before `main`: https://godbolt.org/z/j5WjrY

Comment: Why wouldn't it be safe? There's no resources allocated anywhere.

Comment: `Is it safe` What do you mean by "safe"?

Comment: @NathanaelDemacon now add another constructor after your one and it won't be called. Is it safe to not call a constructor?

Comment: @Lundin @KamilCuk I was wondering if there are other instructions called between the constructor and `main` that may be disrupted by the constructor? I will update the question as it isn't clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be safe.

Typically, all such constructors are called by the "C runtime" (CRT) before `main()` is called. Most often this is done at the end of all set-up, so static storage variables etc have already been initialized. The order of such initializations isn't specified by any standard however, which is about the only problem you might encounter. If your constructor is executed before static storage initialization, any such variable will have indeterminate values.

This contrived program could perhaps in theory be problematic:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void final_words (void)
{
  static int time_to_die = 1;

  if(time_to_die==1)
    puts("My kingdom for a horse!");
}

__attribute__((constructor))
void init(void)
{
    atexit(final_words);
    exit(0);
}

int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

In case `init` is called before `.data` initialization, then `time_to_die` has an indeterminate value, not necessarily `1`. And since `exit` is called before `main()` is executed, there is no guarantee that the variable is initialized. Since the only guarantee C makes is that all static storage duration variables are guaranteed at some point before `main()` is called.

In practice, whoever made the CRT most likely placed constructor calls at a sensible place though, even if there is no standard guaranteeing the order of initialization and constructor calls, like for example C++ would do. Every CRT code with constructor support I've ever seen placed constructor calls just before `main()` is called. The mainstream gcc CRTs seem to do this too, I tried out the above code both in libc/Linux and Mingw/Windows, no problems.

Comment: Since I will use the constructor to edit `argc` and `argv` I guess it's fine then! Thanks you, that's the answer I was seeking for :)

Comment: @NathanaelDemacon I don't quite see how argc and argv would end up passed to your constructor instead of main(), but maybe that part is documented somewhere.

Comment: `argc` and `argv` are passed to constructors on glibc, though it might be implementation defined. I'm targeting for Linux so I personally don't mind.